# Does SQL Server recreate mdf file for TempDB on restart every time?

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-administration, tempdb

Does SQL Server recreate the primary files, secondary files for the `TempDB` database every time the server is restarted? Or does it just refresh the `.mdf`, `.ndf` or log files every time the server restarts?

Comment: the answer is a 5 second search away....

Comment: Yes. but I am having a bit confusion over the mdf file recreation ,that Whether it deletes the mdf also when server shut and again recreates a mdf file when server restarts.

Answer (score 2):

As per [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms190768.aspx) documentation, yes it is re-created everytime SQL Server is started:

> Operations within tempdb are minimally logged. This enables transactions to be rolled back. tempdb is re-created every time SQL Server is started so that the system always starts with a clean copy of the database. Temporary tables and stored procedures are dropped automatically on disconnect, and no connections are active when the system is shut down. Therefore, there is never anything in tempdb to be saved from one session of SQL Server to another. Backup and restore operations are not allowed on tempdb.

Comment: And does it recreates the files on the same drive path as earlier ?

Comment: The location *where* the database is created is defined in SQL Server - so yes, unless you **change it**; it will be the same location on disk